# How to get a variable from a table index

Tags: lua, roblox

How would I compare table indexes to corresponding variables?

```
local var1 = 0
local var2 = 5
local var3 = 10

local MyTable = {math.random(0, 10), math.random(0, 10), math.random(0, 10)}

for i, v in ipairs(MyTable) do
    if v = var..i then    --[[ trying to test if the indexed value is equal to
                         the corresponding variable with v = var..i doesnt work ]]
        print("Index "..i.." is equal to variable "..i)
    end
end
```

This can technically just be done with `if i == var(x) then.. elseif...` but for larger tables that just gets messy and I want to be able to have an easier way to do it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why are you comparing variables to values stored in a table? Are you trying to find the index of a matching value? This feels like you're asking how to do something that might be solved an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the original variables in a table:

```
local var = {0, 5, 10}

local MyTable = {}
for i = 1, 3 do
  MyTable[i] = math.random(0, 10)
end

for i, v in ipairs(MyTable) do
  if v == var[i] then
    print("Index "..i.." is equal to variable "..i)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might be solved in another way, But if you want to compare variables with table values use this :**

```lua
var1 = 0
var2 = 5
var3 = 10

local MyTable = {math.random(0,10),math.random(0,10),math.random(0,10)}

function GetVariableByValue(val)
    if val == nil then return false end
    for variableName, value in pairs (_G) do
        if val == value then return variableName end
    end
    return false
end

for key , value in ipairs(MyTable) do
    local variableName = GetVariableByValue(value)
    if variableName then
        print("Value : "..value.." is equal to variable : "..variableName);
    else
        print("Value : "..value.." isn't equal to any variable.");
    end
end
```

if MyTable doesn't match variables values you will get this message :
'Value : Number isn't equal to any variable.'